# Java regex wildcard not accepted

Tags: java, regex

```
String depends2 = "success(job1) AND n(job2)";
depends2  = depends2.replaceAll("[\\s].(?i)[snd][\\s]*\\(", "");     
System.out.println(depends2);
```

I expect this to output

```
success(job1) ANDjob2)
```

Instead it outputs

```
success(job1) AND n(job2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[\\s].(?i)[snd]` This in your regex ensures that there must a character present inbetween the space and `n` (*followed by zero or more spaces  plus `(` symbol*). But there isn't a character actually. So your regex fails and returns the original string without doing any replacements.

```
String depends2 = "success(job1) AND n(job2)";
depends2  = depends2.replaceAll("\\s(?i)[snd]\\s*\\(", "");     
System.out.println(depends2);
```

**Output:**

```
success(job1) ANDjob2)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
(?i)                     set flags for this block (case-
                         insensitive) (with ^ and $ matching
                         normally) (with . not matching \n)
                         (matching whitespace and # normally)
[snd]                    any character of: 's', 'n', 'd'
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
\(                       '('
```

Comment: You are right of course - my bad i did a typo. I was looking for [\s.](?i)[snd][\s]*\(   meaning at least one space and I put the . outside :)